# How can I make a scatter plot of an r data frame where some cells have complex numbers?

Tags: r

What is the best way to produce a scatter plot from a data frame when some cells have complex numbers?

With no complex numbers I can use:

```
noc_test <- data.frame("x" = c(0, 1),
                       "y" = c(1, 0))
plot(x = noc_test[[1]], y = noc_test[[2]])
```

Is there a way to produce a scatter plot which does not discard the imaginary part for the following data frame?

```
c_test <- data.frame("x" = c(0, sqrt(-1+0i)),
                     "y" = c(-sqrt(-1+0i), 0))

#Note: the plot below discards the imaginary part
plot(x = c_test[[1]], y = c_test[[2]])
```

FYI, this issue came up on an experimental project (not a real world one).

**Edits**
The comments made me realize I wasn't specific enough.  I need a plot function general enough to work even when all cells in a 2 x 2 data frame have real and imaginary parts.  The end goal is to have a plot method that can quickly plot the 2x2 identity plus the 3 Pauli matrices (but formatted as R dataframes); in addition, the plot method should be able to plot arbitrary transformations of this set of data frames.  The purpose is to have an object that I can use to quickly test how a transformation acts on Pauli matrices formatted as data frames (mostly for experimental/tinkering/development purposes).

For now, I will add the following test to the method I am using:

```
#Create data frame containing cells with complex numbers
x <- data.frame("x" = c(0, sqrt(-1+0i)),
                     "y" = c(-sqrt(-1+0i), 0))

#Test for cells with non-zero imaginary numbers and conditionally plot
if (Im(x[[1]][[1]]) != 0 || Im(x[[2]][[1]]) != 0 || 
    Im(x[[1]][[2]]) != 0 || Im(x[[2]][[2]]) != 0){
  x <- data.frame(Re = c(Re(x[[1]][[1]]), Re(x[[2]][[1]]),
                              Re(x[[1]][[2]]), Re(x[[2]][[2]])),
                       Img = c(Im(x[[1]][[1]]), Im(x[[2]][[1]]),
                               Im(x[[1]][[2]]), Im(x[[2]][[2]])))
  
  plot(x = x[[1]], y = x[[2]], xlab = "Real 2", ylab = "Img 2", 
       main = "sig2", col = c("red", "red", "blue", "blue"), 
       pch = c(1, 1, 4, 4))
} else {
  plot(x = x[[1]], y = x[[2]], xlab = "x2", ylab = "y2", 
       main = "sig2")
}
```

I'll probably do something more formal later, but this works for the purpose of visualizing transformations of Pauli matrices (as data frames).

Comment: What do you want the plot to look like, i.e. how is the scatterplot supposed to represent the real and imaginary parts? To include all of the information here, you would need a 4-dimensional plot (Re(x), Im(x), Re(y), Im(y)) rather than a 2-D plot ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use `Im` to note that those numbers are imaginary. Some resources [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/complex.html) and [here](http://www.oranlooney.com/post/complex-r/)

```
c_test <- data.frame("x" = c(0, sqrt(-1+0i)),
                     "y" = c(-sqrt(-1+0i), 0))
```

Use `Im` while plotting

```
plot(x = Im(c_test[[1]]), y = Im(c_test[[2]]))
```

[image: example]

Comment: Thank you.  Your  response was useful but it made me realize that I wasn't clear enough when asking my question.   I should have asked for something general enough to handle complex numbers in all cells.